# Can you tell if an elasticsearch index is being reindexed?

Tags: elasticsearch

I changed one of my mappings so I started a reindex using kopf. How can I tell when the reindex is done?

I've tried searching the output of the following:

```
curl -GET http://example-elastic:9200/logstash-2015.03.31/_status?pretty
curl -GET http://example-elastic:9200/_cat/indices
curl -GET http://example-elastic:9200/_stats/indices
```

**Update**

I started the reindex with the kopf plugin. (Removed incorrect indexing command from question)

**Update2**

I figured out how to see the last index date, but it seems to me like there is a better way to tell if it is currently being indexed.

Works on OSX

```
FOO=logstash-2015.03.31
curl -s -XGET "http://example-elastic:9200/l$FOO?pretty" | grep creation_date | sed  s'/[^0-9]//g' | date -j

Wed Apr  8 16:42:23 MDT 2015
```

**Update3**

I installed [a plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch-reindex) to give more feedback of how long an index takes.

```
 elasticsearch-reindex -f http://example-elastic:9200/logstash-2015.03.22/string -t http://example-elastic:9200
```

It looks like the indexing procedure takes a long time. 5 minutes in, and it is still at 2%

```
...
reindexing [=-----------------------------] 165200/8492680(2%) 158.1 7971.1s
reindexing [=-----------------------------] 165300/8492680(2%) 158.5 7984.9s
reindexing [=-----------------------------] 165400/8492680(2%) 158.5 7981.0s
```

Is there a way to see this progress from elasticsearch?

Comment: are you using some plugin? The two I checked seem to work differently than in your example and the current Elasticsearch documentation describes reindexing also differently.

Comment: Yes jkbkot  I am using kopf, I I've removed the incorrect command.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [cat api](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_cat_api.html) and in particular, the output of `/_cat/nodes?help`.  You'll probably want to monitor the indexing ops with:

`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v&h=indexing.index_current'`